# How to make a Python program automatically prints what matched after iterating through lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, brute-force

I have this Python code:

```
with open('save.data') as fp:
    save_data = dict([line.split(' = ') for line in fp.read().splitlines()])

with open('brute.txt') as fp:
    brute = fp.read().splitlines()

for username, password in save_data.items():
    if username in brute:
        break
else:
    print("didn't find the username")
```

Here is a quick explanation; the `save.data` is a file that contains variables of Batch-file game (such as username, hp etc...) and `brute.txt` is a file that contains "random" strings (like what seen in wordlists used for brute-force).

`save.data`:

```
username1 = PlayerName
password1 = PlayerPass
hp = 100
```

As i said before, it's a Batch-file game so, no need to quote strings

`brute.txt`:

```
username
usrnm
username1
password
password1
health
hp
```

So, let's assume that the Python file is a "game hacker" that "brute" a Batch-file's game save file in hope of finding matches and when it does find, it retrieves them and display them to the user.

```
## We did all the previous code
...
>>> print(save_data["username1"])
PlayerName
```

Success! we retrieved the variables! But I want to make the program capable of displaying the variables it self (because I knew that "username1" was the match, that's why I chose to print it). What I mean is, I want to make the program `print` the variables that matched. E.g: If instead of "username1" in `save.data` there was "usrnm", it will surely get recognized after the "bruting" process because it's already in `brute.txt`. So, how to make the program `print` what matched? because I don't know if it's "username" or "username1" etc... The program does :p (of course without opening `save.data`) And of course that doesn't mean the program will search only for the username, it's a game and there should be other variables like gold/coins, hp etc... If you didn't understand something, kindly comment it and I will clear it up, and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `dict` such as this:

```
with open('brute.txt', 'r') as f:
    # First get all the brute file stuff
    lookup_dic = {word.strip(): None for word in f.readlines()}
with open('save.data', 'r') as f:
    # Update that dict with the stuff from the save.data
    lines = (line.strip().split(' = ') for line in f.readlines())
    for lookup, val in lines:
        if lookup in lookup_dic:
            print(f"{lookup} matched and its value is {val}")
            lookup_dic[lookup] = val
# Now you have a complete lookup table.
print(lookup_dic)
print(lookup_dic['hp'])
```

**Output:**

```
username1 matched and its value is PlayerName
password1 matched and its value is PlayerPass
hp matched and its value is 100
{'username': None, 'usrnm': None, 'username1': 'PlayerName', 'password': None, 'password1': 'PlayerPass','health': None, 'hp': '100'}
100
```

Comment: It is it! Thank you! But one last thing, can I turn the variables who matched into  global ones? like we have usrnm, username1, username etc... But only username1 matched, then can I turn it into one variable called username for example and hp to health etc... For future use? (because as I said, I don't know who would match with who, it depends on what variable the game chose to define, it could even be not on the wordlist. Who knows :p )

Comment: Just us `lookup_dic['hp']` as you would use a normal variable.  Or you can do `hp = lookup_dic['hp']`. You should probably look into using class objects for stuff like this though. You will have a much easier time.

Comment: Yes but, how I would be able to know that it's "hp" and not "health" or any other health points refering variable? (because I want to make the program capable of doing it itself without user's help except for the save file path, I'm working on a project) That's why I need to turn whatever hp or health related thing in the wordlist into one variable so with the other ones. And thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do completely. Please add an example to your question that covers your edge cases. Make sure the example covers completely what you are trying to do. You can always just make a `set` of synonyms and treat them all the same.

Comment: Okay let me explain, I've got a wordlist and a save file. Your code did it successfully and knew what matched what, but I don't and so does the user, that's why i added multiple words in the wordlist in case it didn't match, e.g: I used this program against a save file of a game that contains "user_name, userpass and coins" and thankfully the wordlist has their matches, so I want to get the name of the variable matched for future manipulation. BUT, I don't know what is the name of the variable matched, only the program does (I tried to print the "f{lookup}" but it returned only the last varia-

Comment: -ble matched, but i want them all. Like, "user_name" matched, So the program will get it's value and assign it to a variable for example called "main_username" and it will get the variable who matched with health and assign it's value to a variable for example "main_hp" etc... If you still didn't understand I can explain it to you more, just tell me the parts that you didn't understand and I'll try my best. Because this problem blocked my path and I've been searching for days and days, thank you for your help!

Comment: Lets clarify this [somewhere else](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194059/program-clarification).